# Error after installing pip with easy install (on mac)

Tags: python, pip

I tried to download pip with easy install but after installation whenever I type `pip` into the mac terminal it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 271, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2173, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1906, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 211
    except PipError as exc:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and when I try to do `pip install pyopengl`, it gives me the same error. What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Modern pip works with Python 2.6 and higher. It seems you got Python 2.5, so you either need to upgrade Python or use older version of pip.

According to [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html#python-os-support) Python 2.5 was supported through v1.3.1 of pip.

Comment: i have python 2.6.6 installed and i went to check /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions and the only things there are 2.6, 3.4, and Current

Comment: @NicholasMcGinty your stacktrace indicates, that you are using python 2.5. Type `python --version` to verify

Comment: @Alik you're obviously correct regarding 2.5 being the latest version that didn't support `except .. as ..` - but the output of `python --version` might be misleading - that may not be the same Python interpreter `pip` is using. I'd do a `which pip` and then look at the shebang on the first line of that pip script.

Comment: Never mind, there's not point in checking anyway - it says right there in the traceback that `/usr/local/bin/pip` is using `/Library/Python/2.5/`.

Comment: @NicholasMcGinty if `python --version` outputs 2.6.6 then you should be able to follow [this guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip) and get working pip